# CouchDB - Logstash - _changes with CouchDB Filter

Tags: couchdb, logstash-configuration

Our solution requires that *some* of the data created or modified in CouchDB is logged to Elastic Search using LogStash. So far we have been able to configure LogStash to connect to CouchDb via the changes feed however we have not been able to apply a CouchDB filter to the changes feed. How can we configure LogStash to specify and apply a CouchDB filter to the _changes feed and only log records that pass the filter based on a GET parameter?

LogStash Configuration:

```
input {
        couchdb_changes {
                db => "database-members"
                host => "192.168.0.18"
                sequence_path => "/root/.couchdb_seq_database-members"
        }
 }


output {
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
        index => "logstash-database-members-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the logstash plugin does not support filters yet.
if you know a bit of ruby its easy to add though and will roughly go here:

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-couchdb_changes/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/couchdb_changes.rb#L115

you would need to add the filter option to the logstash module and then make sure the request uri that the module creates is according to this doc

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html